# Eclipse Plugin development: How do you prevent another job from running

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

Greetings all.

I have 2 actions: "Find" and "Run". They can be invoked in 3 ways: Find only; Run only; and Find and Run.

I want to put both actions in Jobs.

For the case of "Find and Run", what is the best way in Eclipse to have the "Run" job wait for the "Find" job to complete. Importantly, the "Run" job depends on the results from the Find job.

As I understand it, I could use a lock, or I could use a rule, though the docs indicate that a single rule is the same thing as a lock.

I know I can accomplish this by adding a post-run event onto the Find job which would then invoke the Run job, but I think the platform provides an preferred mechanism for the behavior I need and I wish to use that... just not sure what that mechanism is.

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in the Eclipse FAQ.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_prevent_two_jobs_from_running_at_the_same_time%3F

I'm assuming since it's the answer given in the FAQ that it is, indeed, the best way to solve this problem